PhpMaker Página de Login
Me gustaría saber si hay una forma de customizar la página de Login que te genera el Phpmaker, por ahí vi que se podía creando una exension y no sé que tanto, la verdad se me hace demasiado, pero no sé si sea la única forma.
Alguien que pueda ayudarme?

Hola SRNDiegoG4rz4,  bienvenido, así como está, tu pregunta va a ser cerrada, necesitas editarla y hacerla más especifica, agregando el código sobre el que trabajas.

PHPMaker es una utilidad para generar archivos PHP. Eso significa que puedes editar tus archivos PHP a como se te de la gana. Sino sabes de PHP un cursito de Youtube es suficiente creería yop
